# Stop debugger button not showing in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to stop solution debugging. I can't find the Stop button. 
 It suddenly disappeared and I don't know why !

The button should switch to stop do process the stop function but don't know why its not.

[image]

Comment: I think i reported that as a bug.

Comment: Debug > Stop debugging. You can always change the buttons shown anyway

Comment: Just press "Shift+F5".

Answer (score 1):

I just started having this problem today after adding a few new packages to a project. the packages themselves I believe are not at fault but the additional menu actions that came along with them are. if you 'Right-Click' upon most of the actions along the tool bar, a check list should appear. Unchecking a few menus that were unused by me eventually allowed the Debugging Actions to expand and the Stop action was back. XtraReports was the culprit in my particular case. GL

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the keyboard shortcut Shift-F5 to stop debugging also.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the debug menu, there should be "Stop Debugging" or just press "Shift+F5"